# Unable to add firewall rule "Duplicate Profile"

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

I'm unable to add new rules to my firewall using ufw gui.
In the Log I get the following error.

```
[19/01/16 14:16:43] Error running: /usr/sbin/ufw allow in from any to any port 8000 > WARN: Duplicate profile 'Apache', using last found | WARN: Duplicate profile 'Apache Secure', using last found | WARN: Duplicate profile 'Apache Full', using last found
```

Can anyone explain how I can fix this? It was working fine before I upgraded to 15.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug pertaining this message [Bug Report!](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apache2/+bug/1311423)

Quote:

> You have 2 apaches profiles in your /etc/ufw/applications.d : apache2.2-common and apache2-utils.ufw.profile.
>    Remove one of them

Try it and let me know.